# gpg recv-keys error: DBG: Not enabled <Dirmngr>, keyserver receive failed: Not enabled

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gpg, tor

command:

```
gpg -vvv --debug-all --recv-keys A8BD96F8FD24E96B60232807B3B4C3CECC10C662
```

output:

```
gpg: Note: no default option file '/home/user/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust hashing ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] start
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- # Home: /home/user/.gnupg
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- # Config: /home/user/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK Dirmngr 2.2.4 at your service
gpg: DBG: connection to the dirmngr established
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> GETINFO version
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- D 2.2.4
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> KS_GET -- 0xA8BD96F8FD24E96B60232807B3B4C3CECC10C662
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- ERR 167772339 Not enabled <Dirmngr>
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Not enabled
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> BYE
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] stop
gpg: keydb: handles=0 locks=0 parse=0 get=0
gpg:        build=0 update=0 insert=0 delete=0
gpg:        reset=0 found=0 not=0 cache=0 not=0
gpg: kid_not_found_cache: count=0 peak=0 flushes=0
gpg: sig_cache: total=0 cached=0 good=0 bad=0
gpg: random usage: poolsize=600 mixed=0 polls=0/0 added=0/0
              outmix=0 getlvl1=0/0 getlvl2=0/0
gpg: rndjent stat: collector=0x0000000000000000 calls=0 bytes=0
gpg: secmem usage: 0/65536 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling with this too for a long time. Then I found in the manual for `dirmngr`:

```
       --standard-resolver
              This option forces the use of the system's standard DNS resolver
              code.  This is mainly used for debugging.  Note that on Windows
              a standard resolver is not used and all DNS access will return
              the error ``Not Implemented'' if this option is used.  Using
              this together with enabled Tor mode returns the error ``Not
              Enabled''.
```

So it could be that you have in the file `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf` a line with `standard-resolver`. If you have that, try removing it. Also kill the process `dirmngr` after every change of this file.

That didn't work for me, since dirmngr does something weird with DNS resolving that only works on Linux.

The next step to try would be to try to change the option to `recursive-resolver`.

This also didn't work for me, it gave me errors like `ERR 167772360 Buffer too short <Dirmngr>`.

As a last ditch attempt I added the option `no-use-tor` a the start of `dirmngr.conf`, and this finally worked for me.

Later, it turned out that an ssh "DynamicForwarding" option on port 9050 confused dirmngr into thinking that Tor is in use.

Comment: Tor is blocked in my country and option about Tor helped me. Thanks ) ..

Comment: `no-use-tor` solved the issue for me.